# wiring up new detached garage

Tags: electrical, garage, 240v, underground

K.I.S.S. Keep it simple stupid. Please remember this when responding because I have very little knowledge of home electrical, mechanic by trade.

My House has a 200amp service panel

House panel runs to a 100amp service panel roughly 100' from the home. Has 2 breakers in it and it is primary used to just control 4 lights on the outside of the property.

New Garage is 76' from the 100amp service panel. I am planning on burying the line to the new garage. I will be running a 4 overhead led shop lights, installing 6-8 electrical outlets (accessibility) and a single 220V hook up.

What wire type/size should I use for the run from the panel to the garage? #4 copper, 6-3 UF-B, or something different? I am purchasing the wiring from Menards (like a home depot / lowes). For the wiring inside of the garage to the outlets, 12-2 UF-B?????

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How many square feet is the garage, and what is the 220 outlet going to be used for?

Comment: Even tho the current subpanel is a 100amp panel are you positive it’s fed with 100amps?  Is the breaker in the main panel, in fact, a double pole 100 amp?

Comment: the sub panel that I plan on running off of is a 100amp panel. It is a double pole true 100amp.

Comment: 24 x 36 garage. the 220 outlet will used between a mill and a small welder on occasions

Comment: You can't keep electrical simple or stupid.  Safety is in the details. The same can be said of vehicles and engines, so not new to you.  However home electrical is 90% different from vehicle electrical.  What size is the wire from the 200A to the 100A panel?

Comment: Harper, you are correct. I do not know the size of the wiring from the 200 main panel to the 100 sub panel.

Comment: See if  you can find out for a couple of reasons, first to make sure it's not overbreakered, figure voltage drop, then my general idea is to continue onward with wires of the same ampacity, so an additional breaker is not needed and so you won't sweat amp limits. 100A calls for #3Cu or preferably #1Al if you're pricing, *please do* check out local electrical supply houses. I love Menards but electrical supply is often cheaper, yeah by 11%.  Also is it worth $1.50/foot to you to only have to dig 8" instead of 19"?

Comment: when I get home this afternoon I will look for the wiring size and post up soon as I know. the reason why I'm going with Menards is because I have pretty good chunk of rebate money to spend after purchasing said building that I'm trying to power up

Comment: could not determine the size of the existing wire from the main box to the subpanel